# Laravel: Can't assign organization to user

Tags: laravel

I want to assign an organization to a user. I already have a CRUD of the Organizations and CRUD of the users. I keep getting this in postman:

[image: the /1 is the ID of the user I want to assign org 1 to it.]

This is the controller of the AssignOrgToUser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\organizations;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AssignOrgToUserController extends Controller
{
    public function assignOrg(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $users = User::find($id);
        if(is_null($users)){
            return response()->json(["message"=>"User not found!"], 404);
        }

        $rules=[  
            'organization'=>'required',
        ];
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors(),400);
        }

        $orgs = organizations::where('id', '=', $rules)->first();
        if(is_null($orgs)){
            return response()->json(["message"=>"Organization not found!"], 404);
        }

        $orgs->save()->$user();
        return response(['message'=>"Organization has beed added", $users]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$request->organization` instead of `$rules` in this line:

```
$orgs = organizations::where('id', '=', $rules)->first();
```